# How to install dorodango package manager Scheme language

Tags: linux, git, scheme, package-managers

- I needed to use **Purely Functional Data Structures** in Scheme (pfds),
  so I found a resource for it (https://github.com/ijp/pfds). I cloned
  it using git command, and so far successful.
- I have racket installed and needed these pfds to work. For which
  first I had to install the pfds using a package manager called “dorodango” to
  install pfds on Gitlab (https://gitlab.com/rotty/dorodango.git).
- So the problem now is that how I install  dorodango package manager from
  the resource I found on Gitlab.

Can someone help? Please.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa! If I understand you correctly, this is Much Easier than you think.

First, though, it looks to me like you need to back up many steps.

To install the `pfds` package for racket, you need to do one (and only one) of these two things. Either:

- run `raco pkg install pfds` from the command-line, or if you're not a command-line person,
- Use the `package manager` built into DrRacket.

No need to git clone anything, no need to use dorodango. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something about your situation?

(For more information, check out the [Getting Started with Packages](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/getting-started.html).)